# Unable to count select item

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I facing a problem here when using select.Items.Count.

**situation 1:**

```
<select id="PrimaryArea" style="width: 100px" required tabindex="6" runat="server">
    <option value="A">Item1</option>
    <option value="B">Item2</option>
    <option value="C">Item3</option>
    <option value="D">Item4</option>
</select>
```

In c#

```
int PrimaryAreaCount=PrimaryArea.Items.Count  // return 4
```

**situation 2:** option add programmatically

```
<select id="SecondaryArea" style="width: 100px" required tabindex="7" runat="server">
</select>
```

in Javascript: return correctly when check using javascript

```
var select = document.getElementById("<%= SecondaryArea.ClientID %>");
var js = JSON.stringify(<%= SecondaryTable %>);
var js2 = JSON.parse(js);
var len = js2.length;
var i = 0;
while (i < len) {
    var new_option = new Option(js2[i].ref_desc, js2[i].cd);
    select.options[select.options.length] = new_option;
    i += 1;
}
```

In C#

```
int SecondaryAreaCount=SecondaryArea.Items.Count  // always return 0
```

What should I do to get the right answer for SecondaryAreaCount in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your second scenario correctly, you start with an empty list of items and then add options in JavaScript.

In this case, you can not calculate the correct count in serverside C# code, because the JavaScript will only be executed after the page has been served to the client.

One solution would be to use an additional hidden input to post back the count result.

```
<input id="SecondaryAreaCount" type="hidden" value="0" />

<script>
// your existing JS loop here ...

var countResult = document.getElementById("SecondaryAreaCount");
countResult.value = i; // var i is select.options.length after the while loop

</script>
```